# Excel calculation error when creating new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

Description of my application in Excel:

1. I import data to a sheet called `RAWDATA`
2. Another already existing sheet `Table1` is to be populated by data from cells containing references to `RAWDATA`.
3. The reference `=RAWDATA!$A$1` is in one of the cells of `Table1`.
4. When I run the application, the previously mentioned cell returns `#REF!`.
5. I try to update calculations, manipulate with application calculation manual. I still get `#REF!`.
6. I click in the formula bar of the `#REF!` cell. Press enter. It calculates correctely.

What can I do to fix this?

Note that I can only use worksheet functions for the process of getting values to the table, not VBA code.

Comment: Hi karamell, interesting question! Hard to catch though, given the above info.. Could you try replacing your formula with `=INDIRECT("RAWDATA!$A$1")`? This could work when you get a `#REF!` Error. Just hard guessing..

Comment: Does rebuilding the dependency tree help? Press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+ F9 together to do this.

Comment: Ioannis: It actually works when A1 contains a simple integer. A1 is in my case a date. If i use `=Year(INDIRECT("RAWDATA!$A$1"))` it returns the correct value but `=INDIRECT("Year(RAWDATA!$A$1)")` returns `#REF!`. Thanks.

Comment: brettdj: Still as before unfortunately

Comment: The latter one does not work because 'Year' acts on the cell first, and there is some issue with the cell itself. 'INDIRECT' comes after, having an error argument so returns the error.. if someone knows what is going on under the hood, I'd be very interested to learn as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to postulate a theory that could explain this behavior. However, I would like to listen to an expert's opinion on this matter.

The issue in brief:

- `=RAWDATA!$A$1` returns a `#REF!` error.
- `#REF!` error does not go away with recalculation, but it goes away by:

  1. Using `INDIRECT("=RAWDATA!$A$1")` instead of `=RAWDATA!$A$1`.
  2. Clicking on the formula bar of the `#REF!` cell and pressing enter.

I believe that excel does not recognize the data type that you import from the other application. Therefore, a reference to this data causes the `#REF!` error.

Can you check if this claim is true?
If it is false, it invalidates whatever is written below.

Excel has a built-in automatic conversion mechanism. For example, if a cell is formatted as text but it looks like a number (say " 10 ") then adding a numeric value to that, is legitimate, because excel internally converts that text to a number.

For some reason, the automatic conversion tool of excel does not work when you recalculate the sheet, but it works when you activate the reference cell and press enter (so when **only** the cell is recalculated). Also, it is triggered by `INDIRECT`.

So I tend to believe that the mechanism that infers the cell value type is induced by `INDIRECT` and by pressing enter in the formula bar, but not by recalculating the sheet.

PS: `INDIRECT` is a volatile function (it is reevaluated every time that excel recalculates) but since recalculation does not work in the first place, this is probably irrelevant.

Comment: I tried to refer the cell to a cell containing a string. I still got the `#REF!` error. Thumbs up for the `INDIRECT` solution.